# Как снизить ресурсозатратность при выводе данных

Tags: php, кэширование

Делаю сайт игровой тематики, и вот стоит задача выводить к примеру список игр , и сервера этих игр. Вот такая структура таблиц в базе

```
games
  id
  name

servers
  id
  name
  game_id
```

В таблице с играм: 50записей, и в таблице серверов: 500 записей.

Я вывожу сейчас примерно вот так:

```
$s_get = "SELECT g.*, s.* FROM `servers` INNER JOIN `games` g ON g.id = s.game_id ";
```

После чего, получаю результат: массив, и массив великоват получается: 550записей.

Для каждого пользователя выводить данные из базы - слишком затратно.

Начал хранить данные в "кеше", кеш у меня файловый, но все-равно, когда вывожу данные пользователям - берет уже из кеша данные но затратно как не крути.

Как более правильно и меньше по затрате ресурсов сделать? 
Может быть какие-то системы кеша использовать?

Работаю без фреймворка

Comment: memcache(d), redis. 550 это не много. Не понятно зачем все выбирать? Может поменять логику что бы выбирало только те сервера где зарегистрирован пользователь(фильтровать по user_id)

Comment: @E_p фильтра есть, я для примера написал что выводить много будет..

Comment: Просто, ваш пример надуманный. Такие запросы в настоящих приложениях или не встречаются или обрезаются при помощи (limit). Если существуют такие запросы, то надо менять логику приложения. И еще раз замечу, 550 записей это не много.

Comment: **Redis** / **Memcached** - два самых распространенных приложения для кэширования данных. Работают как сервер, что позволяет использовать данные несколькими машинами.